# xamarin.forms scrollview sticky at the bottom

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a scroll view and inside it there is a stack layout.

I want the scroll view to always present the last item in the stack layout

for example if i create 100 labels in the stack layout with values of 1 to 100 respectively, I want the last label presented in the scroll view to be 100 (from ~75 to 100).

currently I see in the screen labels 1 to 25...

how do i do it ?

Comment: Draw some picture or something. Kind of hard to visualize w/o it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ScrollToAsync method on the ScrollView to move to the end of your ScrollView's content.

```
var lastLabel = ...; 
scrollView.ScrollToAsync(lastLabel, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

Change the true to false if you don't want animations.

Comment: It does not work as expected for Android device. It only scrolls till the second last element. If you find fix for it, please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scrollView.ScrollToAsync(scrollView.Content, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).